# Можно ли улучшить данную программу и ошибка в VS Express 2012?

Tags: c

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2
  3 inline void func(unsigned short (*arr)[4], unsigned short length)
  4 {
  5     unsigned short x;
  6
  7     for(x = 0; x < length; x++) {
  8         printf("[%hu] - %hu\n", x, *(*arr+x) );
  9     }
 10 }
 11
 12 int main(void)
 13 {
 14     unsigned short array[2][4] = {{11, 22, 33, 44}, {55, 66, 77, 88}};
 15
 16     func(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(unsigned short) );
 17
 18     return 0;
 19 }
```

Вопросы:

1. можно ли более эффективно передать в функцию многомерный массив?
2. sizeof(array)/sizeof(unsigned short) предпочтительнее, или достаточно будет передать 8?
3. можно ли как-то по-другому выводить массив (строка 8:... *(*arr+x)), более эффективно?
4. {} в цикле for обязательны, ведь всего один оператор?
5. почему visual studio 2012 express ругается на inline? Вот его вывод:

---

1. Ошибка  1   error C2054: требуется "(" после "inline"   h:\project\1\1\test.c   3   1   1
2. Ошибка  2   error C2057: требуется константное выражение    h:\project\1\1\test.c   3   1   1
3. Ошибка  3   error C2466: невозможно выделить память для массива постоянного нулевого размера    h:\project\1\1\test.c   3   1   1
4. Ошибка  4   error C2085: func: отсутствует в списке формальных параметров   h:\project\1\1\test.c   4   1   1
5. Ошибка  5   error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"    h:\project\1\1\test.c   4   1   1
6. Предупреждение  6   warning C4013: func: нет определения; предполагается "extern" с возвратом типа "int"    h:\project\1\1\test.c   16  1   1

---

Если же убрать inline, то все ОК. А вот gcc все ОК в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx):

> The inline keyword is available only in C++.

Вы компилируете файл как чистый C? Попробуйте `__inline`.

Теперь по пунктам.

1. Поддержка многомерных массивов в чистом C не очень хороша. Концептуально проще всего передавать указатель на первый элемент и размеры по каждой из координат. Ваше объявление `unsigned short (*arr)[4]` будет скорее всего интерпретировано как `unsigned short **arr`.
2. `sizeof(array)/sizeof(unsigned short)` намного лучше, чем константа 8 (размер массива может измениться!) Ещё лучше `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0][0])`.
3. Не думайте о микроэффективности, оптимизатор сам разберётся.
4. Если в теле `for` одна строка, и нет объявления переменных на верхнем уровне, разумеется фигурные скобки можно опустить. Это скорее вопрос стиля, чем возможности.
5. MSVC не поддерживает пока полностью стандарт C99. В более ранних стандартах ключевого слова `inline` не было, и Microsoft добавило своё ключевое слово `__inline`. Пользуйтесь им. Если вы хотите кроссплатформенность, используйте платформоспецифические макросы:

   ```
   #ifdef _MSC_VER
   #define INLINE __inline
   #endif

   #ifdef __GNUC__
   #define INLINE inline
   #endif

   ...

   INLINE void func(...
   ```

Comment: @VladD __inline помогло. Спасибо. И что значит "чистый" С? Есть Си и С++.
1) Вы предлагаете сделать что-то вроде:
<pre>
__inline void func(unsigned short **arr, unsigned short x, unsigned short y)
{
    unsigned short length = 0, ctr;
    length = x + y;

    for(ctr = 0; ctr < length; ctr++)
        printf("[%hu] - %hu\n", ctr, ????) ); // как вывести массив?
}
</pre>
а вызов функции: func(array, 2, 4); ?
2) Почему лучше sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0][0])?

Comment: @dr_kraken: чистый С — это C в отличие от C++.

1) Я предлагаю сделать

    inline void func(unsigned short* arr, unsigned short x, unsigned short y) {
        unsigned short length = x * y, ctr;
        for(ctr = 0; ctr < length; ctr++)
            printf("[%hu] - %hu\n", ctr, arr[ctr]);
    }

Вызов `func(&array[0][0], 2, 4)`.

2) Потому что код не надо будет менять, если вы перейдёте с `short` на `double`.

Comment: @VladD Объясните пожалуйста, почему вы используете именно такую конструкцию - &array[0][0] в вызове функции?

А в аргументах функции func, не лучше ли заменить unsigned short* arr на unsigned short arr[]?

Comment: @dr_kraken: 1) Мне нужно получить указатель на начальный элемент, `&array[0][0]` именно это и делает.

2) Для функции всё равно. Нет, на самом деле всё равно. Почитайте [вот](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) и [вот](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html), там объясняют лучше, чем я.

Comment: Да, @dr_kraken,  тема  массивов и указателей 

(вместе с адресной арифметикой и передачей параметров),

пожалуй, центральная для понимания сути языка Си.

--

Вы уже внимательно прочли ее в K&R?

Comment: @avp Да, читал. И вот, что я понял: допустим, есть массив
`
arr[2][3]. arr, arr, arr[0], &arr[0], &arr[0][0] - дают адрес переменной (arr[0][0]). arr, arr[0], arr[0][0] - дают значение переменной (которое хранится в arr[0][0]).

Но если arr[0] - это указатель на arr[0][0], и содержит его адрес, то если &arr[0] - не должен дать адрес самого указателя? Но он выдает адрес arr[0][0]. И arr (он же указател на указатель) содержит адрес ptr[0] (который является адресом arr[0][0]).
`

Я либо все правильно понял, либо совсем запутался. Помогите.

Comment: @dr_kraken: Ох. Боюсь, точный ответ не поместится в комментарий. Мне кажется, вам всё же стоит полностью прочитать [вот это](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) и убедиться, что вы всё понимаете.

Comment: @VladD Я английский не знаю, мож посоветуете подобное на русском? А на счет моего вопроса: arr[0] - это указатель на arr[0][0]. Он содержит в значении адрес arr[0][0], но почему если &arr[0], он выдает то же значение, т.е. адрес arr[0][0], а не адрес самого указателя arr[0]?

Comment: @dr_kraken, да уж, коротенько тут не получится...

Если коротко, то НЕТ. 

Тут надо понять разницу между настоящим указателем (переменная (т.е. байты в памяти), значением которой является адрес) и

*массивом, как указатель*. 

Имя массива в правой части оператороа присваивания (и аналогичных  других местах) *представляется как указатель*, хотя и не является им на самом деле. Ему **нельзя** присвоить значение (в отличие от настоящего указателя).

Попробуйте написать `arr = &arr[0][0];` Получите (невнятное) сообщение компилятора об ошибке.

--

М.б. кто-нибудь напишет подробней.

Comment: Есть еще один хороший способ постижения языка. 

Писать маленькие примерчики и исследовать их с помощью gdb (это отладчик от GNU, но может и другой подойдет).

Только, вот, документация (и хэлпы) на языке потенциального противника.

Правда, есть еще способ (но он требует понимания ассемблера). Компилируете сишный код в ассемблер (например, gcc -S c.c сделает файл c.s), читаете и думаете.